# how to modify firefox Quantum dev tool fonts?

Tags: css, firefox, font-size

Today, I update my Firefox browser to Firefox Quantum. But when I want to debug my web app,the Dev tool font is very small. Is there any way to adjust???

[firefox dev tool font screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTQn9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Increase the font size of the dev tools  press `ctrl`+`+` and to decrease the font size press `ctrl`+`-`.

**Note:** Make sure that the focus is on dev tools.